# how to create a new webservice (.asmx) in sage framework 3.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, sageframe

In my scenario, I was implementing the sage framework 3.6 and I am trying to add a new web service (.asmx) in modules folder but when I am trying to add a new web service(.asmx) is not available in visual studio 2013.
How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.
The main problem is if you use sage framework 3.6, it is by default takes framework 4.5.1 which means if you trying to add .asmx file in modules folder then this .asmx web service option is not available.If we want to add new webservice(.asmx) in modules folder then we must change the framework 4.5.1 to 4.5 please follow the steps to solve such kind of issue.
select to the webpage design library and right click -> Go to the property pages-->Select the Build tab-->Change into the Framework 4.5 then you will able to add a new web service .asmx file  in your customize module folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the version .Net Framework . Select the appropriate .Net framework version then you can add the web service.